# How can I log Winget?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, winget

I have been trying to write a script that will first run the

```
winget upgrade --all --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --silent
```

command and then log the results of it. Meaning that there will be packages that will fail to install due to hash mismatch - this is OK for me - and there will be ones that will be installed without issues. I want to parse these 2 types of installs: 1) Successful and 2) Failed into 2 tables (`Format-Table` if I understand correctly) inside a .log file in a folder set up by me.

The part I am having major issues is that I cannot fetch the return codes (ie, did the package install or did it fail to?) that winget throw, and based on that I cannot parse the output into those 2 tables consisting of: AppID, Name (of software), Size (of package), Date (of install or failure to install)

Can someone please help me?

Tried looking for this in the official winget documentation and  couldn't find anything. They do mention `--verbose`,  `--verbonse-logs` and `--open-logs` but they don't do what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Can you reproduce a failing installation? How does the output look like when an installation fails?

Comment: @Olaf  When I cancel an installation for example, this message is thrown: "You cancelled the installation.
Installer failed with exit code: 22"

Comment: Hmmm, and what exactly is your question? I'd assume a successful installation returns the `code:0`. Am I right?

Comment: @Olaf My question is how can I make the script log whether a installation was successful or not, and output the results into those 2 tables

Comment: Well, I don't see the creation of any table in your code at all. I'd start small with capturing the ouput of the command in the first place. You could try to use [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.4) for that.

Comment: In the offical documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade it's told about parameter `--log` with following comment: "Directs the logging to a log file. You must provide a path to a file that you have the write rights to."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `winget` CLI you will need to parse the text that the executable puts into the command line output. However, if you use the [Microsoft.WinGet.Client](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client/) PowerShell Module, you can store the result of `Install-WinGetPackage` into a variable and access the `Status` and `InstallerErrorCode` properties or access them directly through the Pipeline

```
PS C:\Users\Trenly> Install-WinGetPackage Google.Chrome | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,InstallerErrorCode

Name          Status       InstallerErrorCode
----          ------       ------------------
Google Chrome InstallError                  3
```

To do this in the upgrade flow, you would need to use `Get-WinGetPackage` to get the list of packages that are on the machine, filter by the property `IsUpdateAvailable`, pass that through to `Update-WinGetPackage`, and then get the desired properties from the output.

This command should do the trick -

```
Get-WinGetPackage | Where-Object {$_.IsUpdateAvailable} | Update-WinGetPackage | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,InstallerErrorCode
```

Example output -

```
PS C:\Users\Trenly> Get-winGetPackage | Where-Object {$_.IsUpdateAvailable} | Update-WinGetPackage | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,InstallerErrorCode

Name                   Status       InstallerErrorCode
----                   ------       ------------------
GitHub Desktop         Ok                            0
Corsair iCUE5 Software InstallError         3221226525
Node.js                Ok                            0
```